# Hamiltonian system and algebraic relations between variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, dynamical-systems, change-of-variable, hamilton-equations

Consider an Hamiltonian function
$$
H(q_1,q_2,p_1,p_2)=p_1\, F_1(q_1,q_2) + p_2\, F_2(q_1,q_2).
$$
Assume  $q_2=g(q_1)$ for some function $g$.

I am interested in seeing what does this property imply on the dual variables $p_1,p_2$.

- First, we have:
  $$
  \dot p_1(t) = \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_1}(q_1(t),q_2(t),p_1(t),p_2(t))
   = \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_1}(q_1(t),g(q_1(t)),p_1(t),p_2(t))
  $$
- Second, define $\tilde H$ such that:
  $H(q_1,q_2,p_1,p_2) = \tilde H(q_1,p_1,p_2)$ where $q_2$ has been substitute by $g(q_1)$.
  Then
  $$
  \begin{array}{l}
  \frac{\partial \tilde H}{\partial q_1}(q_1,p_1,p_2) &=\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_1}(q_1,g(q_1),p_1,p_2) + g'(q_1)\, \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_2}(q_1,g(q_1),p_1,p_2) \\
  &=   \dot p_1 +  \mathbf{g'(q_1)\,  \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_2}(q_1,g(q_1),p_1,p_2)}
  \end{array}
  $$
  but what does correspond this "correcting" term in bold ?

What can we say more ? Is it possible to define an Hamiltonian dynamics with only one state variable ?